# C++ std::async run on main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++11, std

IS there a way of running a function back on the main thread ?

So if I called a function via Async that downloaded a file and then parsed the data. It would then call a callback function which would run on my main UI thread and update the UI ?

I know threads are equal in the default C++ implementation so would I have to create a shared pointer to my main thread. How would I do this and pass the Async function not only the shared pointer to the main thread but also a pointer to the function I want to rrun on it and then run it on that main thread ?

Comment: You cannot provide a callback to `std::async`, you need to poll for the readiness of the value from the thread that you are interested in (or from a different thread and then message the UI thread). Of course, you could wrap the real function in a different function that sends the message for you...

Comment: You can use `get()` to synchronize with a thread.

Comment: Would signals work with this ?

Comment: In general, you can't just run a function on another thread. _When_  would that other thread run it? The big exception is running a function on a new thread, or a free thread in a threadpool. They're by definition not running anything else, so they can run your function right now.

Comment: Would having the mainthread poll the future be a viable solution, so if I had a timer on the main thread that called a function that checked if an action had been done and then called the callback with the futures result, would that work ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have been reading *[C++ Concurrency in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770)* and chapter four (AKA "The Chapter I Just Finished") describes a solution.

### The Short Version

Have a shared `std::deque<std::packaged_task<void()>>` (or a similar sort of message/task queue).  Your `std::async`-launched functions can push tasks to the queue, and your GUI thread can process them during its loop.

### There Isn't Really a Long Version, but Here Is an Example

#### Shared Data

```
std::deque<std::packaged_task<void()>> tasks;
std::mutex tasks_mutex;
std::atomic<bool> gui_running;
```

#### The `std::async` Function

```
void one_off()
{
    std::packaged_task<void()> task(FUNCTION TO RUN ON GUI THREAD); //!!
    std::future<void> result = task.get_future();

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(tasks_mutex);
        tasks.push_back(std::move(task));
    }

    // wait on result
    result.get();
}
```

#### The GUI Thread

```
void gui_thread()
{
    while (gui_running) {
        // process messages
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(tasks_mutex);
            while (!tasks.empty()) {
                auto task(std::move(tasks.front()));
                tasks.pop_front();

                // unlock during the task
                lock.unlock();
                task();
                lock.lock();
            }
        }

        // "do gui work"
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

1. I am (always) learning, so there is a decent chance that my code is not great.  The concept is at least sound though.
2. The destructor of the return value from `std::async` (a `std::future<>`) will block until the operation launched with `std::async` completes (see [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) ), so waiting on the result of a task (as I do in my example) in `one_off` might not be a brilliant idea.
3. You may want to (I would, at least) create your own threadsafe MessageQueue type to improve code readability/maintainability/blah blah blah.
4. I swear there was one more thing I wanted to point out, but it escapes me right now.

### Full Example

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <thread>


// shared stuff:
std::deque<std::packaged_task<void()>> tasks;
std::mutex tasks_mutex;
std::atomic<bool> gui_running;


void message()
{
   std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}


void one_off()
{
    std::packaged_task<void()> task(message);
    std::future<void> result = task.get_future();

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(tasks_mutex);
        tasks.push_back(std::move(task));
    }

    // wait on result
    result.get();
}


void gui_thread()
{
    std::cout << "gui thread: "; message();

    while (gui_running) {
        // process messages
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(tasks_mutex);
            while (!tasks.empty()) {
                auto task(std::move(tasks.front()));
                tasks.pop_front();

                // unlock during the task
                lock.unlock();
                task();
                lock.lock();
            }
        }

        // "do gui work"
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}


int main()
{
    gui_running = true;

    std::cout << "main thread: "; message();
    std::thread gt(gui_thread);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        // note:
        // these will be launched sequentially because result's
        // destructor will block until one_off completes
        auto result = std::async(std::launch::async, one_off);

        // maybe do something with result if it is not void
    }

    // the for loop will not complete until all the tasks have been
    // processed by gui_thread

    // ...

    // cleanup
    gui_running = false;
    gt.join();
}
```

#### Dat Output

```
$ ./messages
main thread: 140299226687296
gui thread: 140299210073856
140299210073856
140299210073856
140299210073856
140299210073856
140299210073856
```

Comment: Ahh thank you :) so I just need to poll it once every so often

Comment: With a bit of improvement via `std::condition_variable`, this solution can work without `sleep()`.

Comment: `auto result = std::async(std::launch::async, one_off);` This part will keep your program waiting until the async tasks are over. You can easily experience this if your async functions are calculating something expensive. Use `std::make_unique<std::future<void>*>(new auto(std::async(std::launch::async, one_off))).reset();` to bypass this issue and handle the future results some other way. See the example: http://cpp.sh/7rdwn

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `std::launch::deferred` ? Passing this parameter to std::async makes the task executed on the calling thread when the get() function is called for the first time.