# C++11 threading: platform agnostic way to run std::asynch on main thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354260/c-stdasync-run-on-main-thread), but the accepted answer is all but platform neutral, nor does it fit into usual applications (where you have no control over the main thread loop).

So what I'm after is rather similar to what libdispatch does (specifying the main thread queue to run something there triggered from a background thread), but with pure C++11. I would also like to avoid timers as they usually have a very low priority and may execute unreliably (depending on the load of the main thread).

The usage could be something as simple as:

```
run_on_main_thread([]() { myGui.refresh(); };
```

called in a background thread after finishing some work. Ideally, it would allow both: synchronous and asynchronous execution.

Of course I'm not asking for a full solution, but rather some ideas how this can be implemented with pure C++11. I can even imagine smaller platform dependent parts (in a neutral wrapper) which allow to control the execution (like the native handle from a thread). But I don't see how to make a task run on a specific thread (be it the main thread or a manually created background thread).

Comment: Are you asking how to write an event loop? Say, a producer-consumer queue of `std::function<void()>`, with main thread running a consumer (there's no shortage of producer-consumer queue implementations).

Comment: Applications today have already an even loop. I don't need to write one. But I also have no control over that and I really don't wanna care, as this is platform specific. I'm looking for an idea to inject tasks into the main thread in a platform neutral way, similar as GCD (libdispatch) does with it's work queues.

Comment: So, you are asking how you can write generic, portable, framework-agnostic code that can magically communicate with every application-specific event loop ever written, or one that would be written in the future. I do not believe such a feat is possible.

Comment: Exactly, looks like you got my point 100%. I love magic.

Comment: I think I could demonstrate that, especially in light of "works with any framework current and *future*" requirement, this task is equivalent to [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Basically, whatever approach you come up with, I can then invent an event loop system designed specifically to break it. Anyway, best of luck - you'll need it.